# How to stop ASP.NET MVC view rendering inside cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is proper way to stop cshtml view rendering after redirect?
Can I do return inside cshtml?

```
@{
 if (someCondition) {       
        Response.Redirect("/login");
        return;
    }
 }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
```

Comment: the proper way is to specify your logic in the Controller, not in the view

Comment: That is solution for ideal world. But In my case I have access only to view.

Comment: get access to the controller then, or specify a javascript redirect if you absolutely must.

Comment: In my case I need to stop rendering because it does not have all data to render. So JS redirect is not solution.

Comment: why do you not have access to the controller?

Comment: Rather than redirect, why not just conditionally render the 'sections' you have the data for and conditionally skip the 'sections' you do not have data for?

Comment: also, you can just do `Response.Redirect`, though it's very dirty to do so and could have some unforseen consequences. Such logic should be in the controller.

Comment: @if(Model.DataINeed != null){ [Render Something] }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this may be a duplicate question, to which the short answer is:

**It's perfectly valid to `return;` from within cshtml; however there is usually a better way.**

Sources:

- [Abort/skip/cancel the rendering of a Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742865/abort-skip-cancel-the-rendering-of-a-razor-view)
- [ASP.NET MVC3 Razor - How to conditionally quit or end or return or break a partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010010/asp-net-mvc3-razor-how-to-conditionally-quit-or-end-or-return-or-break-a-parti)
- [Is 'Exit Sub' from within a razor view a concern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733072/is-exit-sub-from-within-a-razor-view-a-concern)